# Доступ к открытой вкладке из расширения Chrome

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Пишу расширение для Chrome браузера. На повестке имеется следующая задача. Необходимо открыть новую вкладку и выполнить в ней JS код (например изменить background-color элемента body). Пишу следующее:

**background.js**

```
var created = chrome.tabs.create({
    url: "https://google.com/",
    active: true
}, function (tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        code: "document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red'"
    });
});
```

Новая вкладка успешно открывается, но дальше никаких изменений. Похоже где-то перемудрил с кодом.

Мой **manifest.js** имеет необходимые разрешения и работает для любого домена:

```
"permissions": ["<all_urls>", "webNavigation", "tabs", "activeTab"],
```

Если у кого-то есть опыт, хотелось бы увидеть простой пример открытия вкладки и выполнения в ней JS кода.

Answer (score 0):

Друзья, пока ожидал ответа, нашёл решение самостоятельно. Следующий код успешно открывает новую вкладку и выполняет в ней JS:

```
var created = chrome.tabs.create({
    url: "https://google.com",
    active: true
}, function (tab) {
    insertJs(tab.id);
});

function insertJs (tabId) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
        code: "document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';"
    });
}
```